# how to sort a user-inputted list

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I want to sort a list of strings alphabetically.

Here is my code:

`lis =list( input("list"))
print (sorted (lis, key=str.lower))`

input:`['constitute', 'Eflux', 'Intrigue', 'Sedge', 'Stem', 'Whim']`

output:`[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', 'E', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'W', '[', ']', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'x']`

I have no idea why.

Comment: `input` doesn't evaluate expressions in python 3. You need to `ast.literal_eval` the list first, or you're sorting the characters of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to what python 2 `input` does, python 3 `input` doesn't evaluate the input anymore (acts like `raw_input` did), for safety reasons (`input` was a hidden `eval` function)

The code you showed worked fine in python 2, but needs some adaptations for python 3.

In your case, you need to `ast.literal_eval` the list first, which parses and performs a safe evaluation of literals only (just what you need) or you're sorting the characters of the inputted string. Like this:

```
import ast
lis = ast.literal_eval(input("list").lstrip())
print (sorted (lis, key=str.lower))
```

(adding `lstrip()` so leading spaces are trimmed if any, `ast.literal_eval` cares about indentation)

Comment: This is pretty cool but is there a way to combine this with list mapping say `l = ast.literal_eval(list(map(str, input().strip().split(' '))))` because I get this `ValueError: malformed node or string: ['two', 'one', 'three']`

Comment: you don't have to map to string or split, that would destroy the internal structure of the input (what if som strings contain spaces?). the parsing of the list is already done by `ast.literal_eval()`. Adding `strip()` is a nice touch because `ast.literal_eval` cares about indentation. Edited. What is the exact input that causes the error? because `['two', 'one', 'three']` is fine.

Comment: All is good now. There was a typo on my side. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it:

```
string=['constitute', 'Eflux', 'Intrigue', 'Sedge', 'Stem', 'Whim']
for i in range(len(string)):
    string[i]=string[i].lower()
s=sorted(string)
print(s)
```

This way, all the **list elements** are converted into *lower case* and then `sorted() function` sorts all the list elements. The output:

```
['constitute', 'eflux', 'intrigue', 'sedge', 'stem', 'whim']
```

Hope this was useful!

Answer (score -1):

input() function returns **one string** at once, not a regular list as you entered. 
so you need to feed it with a string of the items in the list like so:

```
lis = input('Enter your list items seperated by a space: ')
lis = lis.split()
lis.sort(key=str.lower) 
print(lis)
```

there are many other ways to do it but this is the most preferred one.

Comment: But the input is an actual `list`, not a series of strings.

Comment: input is the representation of a list, as strings. `split` won't work (it splits on spaces)